# Failed to open property list: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 44

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]

There is a problem with my info.plist. When I try to build an application in Xcode, I just get an error and click on info.plist shows this error. How can I resolve this issue with a react native project? All I want to do is run the application.

Here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>**********</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Provided file doesn't even have line 44, I suspect you have a problem in another property file (there might be more than one in Xcode projects).

Comment: @lazarevzubov I updated file right now

Comment: You have `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>` not followed by a `<string>someValue</string>`... That's the error it's expecting for the next line to be like that, but instead it's `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>`...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

You have two consecutive keys, and the value for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` is expected to be a String, to next line after `<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>` should be `<string>some text</string>`

So change it:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Explain why user should allow to your app to access Photo Library</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```